# Prestashop install error - array_key_exists parameter on Language class

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to get Prestashop working with Docker and Composer.

I use assistant for installation. This assistant got an error on module installation part.

`/install-dev/index.php?installModules=true`

```
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/classes/Language.php on line 645
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  251136  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0163  2377856 InstallControllerHttp::execute( )   .../index.php:31
3   0.2252  4246288 InstallControllerHttpProcess->process( )    .../controllerHttp.php:173
4   0.2253  4246656 InstallControllerHttpProcess->processInstallModules( )  .../process.php:97
5   0.2591  9068744 InstallModelInstall->installModules( )  .../process.php:226
6   0.2636  9900216 ModuleCore::getInstanceByName( )    .../install.php:729
7   0.2636  9900664 ModuleCore::coreLoadModule( )   .../Module.php:1107
8   0.2651  10219816    Adapter_ServiceLocator::get( )  .../Module.php:1142
9   0.2651  10219816    Core_Foundation_IoC_Container->make( )  .../Adapter_ServiceLocator.php:52
10  0.2651  10219952    Core_Foundation_IoC_Container->doMake( )    .../Core_Foundation_IoC_Container.php:170
11  0.2651  10220832    Core_Foundation_IoC_Container->makeInstanceFromClassName( ) .../Core_Foundation_IoC_Container.php:157
12  0.2651  10221608    newInstance ( ) .../Core_Foundation_IoC_Container.php:124
13  0.2651  10222472    ThemeConfigurator->__construct( )   .../Core_Foundation_IoC_Container.php:124
14  0.2651  10227256    LanguageCore::getLanguage( )    .../themeconfigurator.php:43
15  0.2651  10227400    array_key_exists ( )    .../Language.php:645
```

Error comes from this language part:

```
public static function getLanguage($id_lang)
{
    if (!array_key_exists((int)$id_lang, self::$_LANGUAGES)) {
        return false;
    }
    return self::$_LANGUAGES[(int)($id_lang)];
}
```

I have nothing else and I don't understand why `self::$_LANGUAGES` is `null`.

I'm using latest 1.6.1.4 version of PrestaShop from GitHub.

Anybody got a similar issue? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think they forgot to add the following code in `getLanguage()` method:

```php
if (!self::$_LANGUAGES) {
    Language::loadLanguages();
}
```

This code is present in method `getLanguages()`:

```php
public static function getLanguages($active = true, $id_shop = false, $ids_only = false)
{
    if (!self::$_LANGUAGES) {
        Language::loadLanguages();
    }

    $languages = array();
    foreach (self::$_LANGUAGES as $language) {
        if ($active && !$language['active'] || ($id_shop && !isset($language['shops'][(int)$id_shop]))) {
            continue;
        }

        $languages[] = $ids_only ? $language['id_lang'] : $language;
    }

    return $languages;
}
```

But missing from `getLanguage()`:

```php
public static function getLanguage($id_lang)
{
    if (!array_key_exists((int)$id_lang, self::$_LANGUAGES)) {
        return false;
    }
    return self::$_LANGUAGES[(int)($id_lang)];
}
```

Comment: Not sure of that. We are talking about vendor prestashop code here. BTW, if I try the installation with the same code but not on Docker image, this is working.